# R and sra toolkit - odd system() behavior

Tags: r, cmd, system, command-line-tool

In order to extract some fastq data from NCBI's sequence read archive I've downloaded and installed the [sra toolkit](https://github.com/ncbi/sra-tools/wiki/01.-Downloading-SRA-Toolkit) for Windows. In order to test if it is setup correctly, I opened cmd, navigated to the directory and typed in the command `fasterq-dump --split-files SRR7647019`. It downloads the file SRR7647019.sra as expected and splits it into fastq files.

Then I've tried the same command in RStudio, wrapping the `system()` command around it: `system(fasterq-dump --split-files SRR7647019)`. However, R always returns

> An error occured: unrecognized tool FASTER~2.EXE
> If this continues to happen, please contact the SRA Toolkit at https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/

as well as the number 75 (probably an error code).

Any idea why I'm not able to run fasterq-dump.exe from R? How could it be solved?

Thanks a lot for suggestions in advance!

Comment: Are you using the R terminal or RStudio? RStudio uses a different set of environmental variables, thus it might not find the `fasterq-dump` executable.

Comment: @danlooo Sorry, I use RStudio, not R terminal. However, I just checked whether this would make a difference. No, it doesn't the same error is returned.

Comment: What is your result of the R command `Sys.getenv("PATH")`? Is `fasterq-dump` inside one of these folders?

Comment: @danlooo No. It's in another folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to call the terminal shell explicitly to bypass the environmental variables which might get overwritten by RStudio:

```
system("cmd.exe /k fasterq-dump --split-files SRR7647019")
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice suggestion. However, I have to disappoint you. The output remains the same :(

Comment: Do you have access to Docker desktop or Windows subsystem for Linux? This will make things much easier in the world of Bioinformatics.

Comment: Nope. Well, I know. Nevertheless quite funny because system() worked for me on other apps always well. But thanks so far for your will to help!

Answer (score 1):

Tried the whole thing again, but this time with `fasterq-dump-orig`: `system(fasterq-dump --split-files SRR7647019)`. And guess what ... it worked! Nevertheless, it would be nice to know why I'm able to exectue fasterq-dump-orig from R, but not fasterq-dum ...

Comment: Does this work?  `system("cmd.exe /k fasterq-dump --split-files SRR7647019")` Here I explicitly tell R to use the default windows terminal

Comment: Furthermore, I've havent foubd a file called `FASTER~2.EXE`... Maybe this fiel is not needed using `fasterq-dump-orig`

Comment: @danlooo: ```system("cmd.exe /k fasterq-dump --split-files SRR7647019")``` finally works! If you want to write another answer, I'll accept it! Thanks! Yes, FASTER~2.EXE doesn't seem to exist at all. Seems like R/RStudio tries to shorten the file name?!

Comment: I revised my answer